# how to make MuleSoft webconsumer connector fields get dynamic values

Tags: wsdl, mulesoft

Invalid wsdl location. 
The property key is not being read.

Steps that I've done so far 
1. create dev.properties file 
2. inside dev. properties file

## Web Service configuration

ccms.web.location=http://[host_name]:[port]/CreateSegmentDEV/CreateSegmentServiceimpl?WSDL

3. I put the ${ccms.web.location} in wsdl location
4. Got error ${ccms.web.location} should be a valid URL or in a file classpath. Please see screenshot that I will upload.

I expected that no error but there is error, invalid wsdl location.
The property key is not being read.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the configuration properties in the global elements and specifiy the property file (dev)?